# Does the word "beach" come from "bleach?"

Tags: etymology

Though there is no widely accepted etymology for the word ***[beach](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/beach)***, one suggestion is that it derives from ***[bleach](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bleach)***, as OED suggests in a possibility without evidence.

> Another conjecture would derive beach < bleach < Old English blǽce, < blác white, with loss of l, of which there is however no evidence.

The idea here is that a beach contains sand and pebbles that are bleached white by the sun.

The earliest definitions of "bleach" are related to whiteness, not to the chemical associated with the term today:

> †1. Whiteness, paleness. Obs.
>
> 1400   Pol. Rel. & L. Poems (1866) 255   Brest & hert was bete to **bleche**.

The more mainstream suggestion regarding "beach" is openly available on [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=beach):

> 1530s, "loose, water-worn pebbles of the seashore," probably from a dialectal survival of Old English bece, bece "stream," from Proto-Germanic *bakiz. Extended to loose, pebbly shores (1590s), and in dialect around Sussex and Kent beach still has the meaning "pebbles worn by the waves." French grève shows the same evolution.

I tried to find other sources of the suggestion that "beach" shares an etymological relationship with "bleach."  It is mentioned on [Word Detective](http://www.word-detective.com/2007/12/strand-beach/):

> As for the origin of “beach,” theories range from the Old Norse “bakki” (“bank,” as of a stream) to the Old English “baece” (stream) to “beach” **being a mutation of “bleach”** (as stones are **bleached** by the sun and water).

I haven't been able to find much more about the question in my own research.

So the question(s):

1. Is there any evidence linking the word "beach" with "bleach?"
2. If not, what is the origin of this suggestion?
3. If there is evidence pointing to an alternative explanation, what is the evidence?

Comment: I mean, I would count the phonetic similarity as minor evidence. I have a broad definition of the word "evidence", though. It doesn't mean it's *good* evidence. The loss of a liquid consonant from a word-initial cluster, while not regular, is not unknown as a possible sound change from Old English to modern English—I can think of one well-established example, the loss of "r" in "speak" and "speech" < OE "sprecan" and "sprǽc/spréc". The sound /l/ is also known to have been lost in at least some English words, such as "as" < "eall swa" and "each" <  "ǽlc".

Comment: @sumelic that's true and it might answer point 2 of my questions.  I'd still be curious if there is any research as to where this proposal came from beyond the evident phonetic similarity.

Comment: The concept of a beach is so fundamental to folks living in western Europe that it seems highly unlikely that the term would newer than "bleach".

Comment: @HotLicks OED could be wrong about that, but it puts "bleach" clearly first and attributes it as a possible origin of "beach."  I was surprised as well upon this finding, since "beach" is a quite common term in English.

Comment: I could see that "bleach" derives from "beach" -- what happens when some object is "beached" for a period of time.

Comment: @HotLicks in case it helps as a starting point for research, OED's earliest citation of "bleach" has a different spelling and comes from this source.  I don't have access to the original source: **c1050   in T. Wright & R. P. Wülcker Anglo-Saxon & Old Eng. Vocab. (1884) I. 465   Pallor, blæco.**  Since the spelling is so different, I cited a different source in my question (the second listed by OED)

Comment: One point I will offer is that the Italian *bianca* (girl's name) and Mandarin *bai* (bai fun is white rice) both mean white with no 'l' there.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I don't think Mandarin has the "bl" phoneme.

Comment: @Lawrence Modern Chinese languages have lost all initial consonant clusters, but Old Chinese almost certainly did have them. 白 _bái_ is generally reconstructed as having initial _*br_, though, and it's not related anyway. In Italian, of course, all instances of /Cl/ became /Cj/, so _blancum_ > _bianca_ is regular there.

Comment: @HotLicks The fact that the concept is essential doesn't mean that the **word** isn't new. Semantic shift can occur even in very common and essential vocabulary. Words for ‘boy’ and ‘girl’, for example, have a striking tendency to be fairly recent words (often borrowings) that have replaced earlier words. Both words are only from around the 13th century in English, for instance, though the concept of boys and girls is of course much older.

Comment: **_bleach_**, originally "whiteness", traces back to Old English and has a continuous development, with the 'modern' sense, "An act of bleaching;  ... A bleaching process; also, a bleached condition," only appearing (according to the OED) in the late 19thC.  **_beach_** (again according to the OED) first appears in 1535: "c1535 _Art Suruey_ 28 The smooth hard beach on the Sea~shoares burnes to a purer white."  If there is a connection (which I'm inclined, given the sequence of dates, to doubt), it would have to be between "bleach=white, and "beech=pebbled seashore".

Comment: @YosefBaskin Italian has lost a large number of *L* sounds: flower is Latin *flora* but *fiori* in Italian. Floor is *piano* but again Latin has *pl-*. That the Italian for *white* is *bianca* is indicative that there should/used to be an *L* in there.

Comment: I am a bit curious as to why this matters.  What is to be learned?

Comment: @HotLicks it seems to me to have the same purpose as any question about etymology.  The site is, after all, specifically for "for linguists, *etymologists*, and serious English language enthusiasts."  I think the question is interesting, and it seems to have at least sparked some conversation.

Comment: @Race there is no regular rule of 'bl'->'b' in English and I don't think there are any isolated other suggestions of isolated pairs with the sound change. Black, blue and bleach are all cognate and have kept the 'l'. And since there is no diachronic evidence (e.g. The shoreline called something like 'bleach', the connection is unlikely.

Comment: @Andrew Leach I thought that in Italian the consonant L and the vowel I could interchange in some sort of inflection, and that the Fiorenza means Florentine for this reason. https://www.behindthename.com/name/fiorenza

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Most likely not.

Longer answer: A negative is usually more difficult to support than a positive. To say there is absolutely no connection between 'bleach' and 'beach' we'd have to know ... everything... and then scan 'everything' for support of the positive and have good reason to say that the support for each of them doesn't work. As that is not really possible we can only give likelihoods, things like in similar circumstances there was no connection. There are all sorts of single instances of phenomena in language that are not rule based, but rules (common patterns) are more common than the single exceptions (there's an argument that needs to be made for that but let's not go so quickly down that rabbit hole).

Here are two situations that are similar:

- Phonetically, there is no regular alternation or sound change in English or in between word initial 'bl' and 'b'.  In English there is no post-plosive liquid drop rule from proto-Germanic, it just doesn't happen. In other languages, Latin -> Italian has 'bl' -> 'bi', but the 'l' is not lost it is more changed to 'i'. (there is a bit of chicken-egg here because these rules must be found by having words of similar meaning sharing lots of similar phonology; but if you throw all the words in together before knowing the rule, a bunch of them would stick together and 'beach/bleach' would be an outlier.
- Semantically, things are a lot more fluid. Word meanings can travel far. 'Black' and 'blue' are actually cognate with 'bleach' (flipping between light and dark colors). So it is not crazy to think that 'beach' is a 'bleached seashore purely by color association. It's just that the known etymologies don't show any evidence for their connection.

So to your 3 questions:

1. No, there is no evidence beyond someone just saying so.
2. We have no idea where that author got their idea (beyond the obvious similarity in spelling)
3. There is no evidence

Comment: This might be another outlier, what about the [etymology of bat](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bat): *flying mouse-like mammal (order Chiroptera), 1570s, a dialectal alteration of Middle English bakke (early 14c.), which is probably related to Old Swedish natbakka, Old Danish nathbakkæ "night bat," and Old Norse leðrblaka "bat," literally "leather flapper," **from Proto-Germanic blak-**, from PIE root *bhlag- "to strike" (see flagellum)...*

Comment: nice find. but yes, looks like an outsider (and also still a questionable derivation)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the first usages in the OED, we see that most of them mean *pebbles,* and the first one might easily mean *pebbles*.

> 1535: The smooth hard beach on the Sea~shoares burnes to a purer white.
>
> 1552:  A Banke of baches throwen up by the Se.
>
> 1566: Wee haled your barke ouer a barre of beach or peeble stones.
>
> 1597   J. Gerard Herball ii. 249   Rowling pebble stones, which those that dwell neere the sea do call Bayche.

And Shakespeare seems to use it to mean the seashore, although twice it specifically means sections of the seashore that are covered by pebbles:

> *Coriolanus*: Then let the pebbles on the hungry beach 
>   Fillip the stars;
>
> *Cymbeline* ... can distinguish 'twixt 
>   The fiery orbs above and the twinn'd stones 
>   Upon the number'd beach?

So it seems to have originally meant *beach pebbles*, and later came to mean *pebbled beaches*, and from there it evolved to its current meaning of *sandy or pebbled beaches*.

So the real question is: did beach pebbles start getting called *beaches* because they were white, or because they came from streams, or for some other reason? One subquestion then is: are British beach pebbles white? Some of them are, and some of them aren't. I don't think we can conclude anything definitively one way or the other.

Comment: though the 1535 use may support the bleach theory

Answer (score 0):

In many languages, the "ba" sound is in words that represent heat. For example. "bake". Beach could likely come from a word like this, even "bake" (in the sun).

I highly doubt that it comes from "bleach". I know no roots that have had loss of an "L" historically.

Comment: You know what I meant. I meant loss of an "L".

Answer (score 0):

bæce in old English

Pronounced as beace with a hard c

Then some influence in spelling when the ae was lost in the language, corrected it the ea. The ce with a similar sound to ch was replaced

Answer (score 0):

According to Oxford Dictionaries the origin of the word [beach](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/beach) is:

> Mid 16th century (denoting shingle on the seashore): perhaps related to Old English bæce, bece ‘brook’ (an element that survives in place names such as Wisbech and Sandbach), assuming an intermediate sense ‘pebbly river valley’

However the same dictionary gives the definition of [bleak](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/bleak) as:

> lacking vegetation and exposed to the elements.

and its origin as:

> Old English blāc ‘shining, white’, or in later use from synonymous Old Norse bleikr; ultimately of Germanic origin and related to bleach.

I can accept the idea that a "beach" is a white or pale area, even shingle beaches are usually composed of quite pale pebbles, but English beaches are pretty "bleak" places and only comfortable on hot days in the height of summer. Sea bathing only became fashionable in the late 18th and early 19th centuries and the idea of going to the beach for fun came even later. Before then people on a beach were putting up with the bleak conditions to do hard, useful and profitable work.

I'm not suggesting that "beach" derives entirely from "bleak" and both words appear to share connections with "bleach" but I do feel that "bleak" could be part of the story.

Answer (score -3):

In many languages, the word for "beach" is something like "plazh"; for example,

```
Bosnian: plaža  Catalan: platja  Czech: pláž  
Polish: plaża   Romanian: plajă  Spanish: playa
```

However, in Maltese, it is "bajja". Malta is in the Mediterranean, and several African languages also have "beach". This leads me to think that the English "beach" came from the Maltese "bajja". Or, it might have come from one of the other African countries (during the American colonization at the beginning of slavery).

Source: https://www.indifferentlanguages.com/words/beach

Comment: The African languages that use the word "beach"  were ex-British colonies, so this proves nothing. As for Malta, also an ex-British colony which gained independence in 1964, you need to trace the origin of *bajja* and find out its pronunciation. But I strongly, strongly doubt that *beach*  is a Maltese loanword, it seems most unlikely.

Comment: and how, pray tell, would a maltese loan word make its way into old english?

Comment: -1 because the pronunciation of bajja, which might have lent some support to your theory, is totally and utterly unrelated to the English pronunciation. See https://forvo.com/word/mt/bajja/, it sounds much closer to "bay", which in Italian is *baia*

Comment: And   *abjad* is Maltese for "white".  There's 30 minutes lost which I'll never regain ...